# Where should I put common utility functions for Perl .t tests?

Tags: perl, testing

I am getting started with [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Test::More), already have a few .t test scripts. Now I'd like to define a function that will only be used for the tests, but across different .t files. Where's the best place to put such a function? Define another .t without any tests and `require` it where needed? (As a sidenote I use the module structure created by [Module::Starter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Module::Starter))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write a module as rjh has demonstrated.  Put it in t/lib/Test/YourThing.pm, then it can be loaded as:

```
use lib 't/lib';
use Test::YourThing;
```

Or you can put it straight in t/Test/YourThing.pm, call it `package t::Test::YourThing` and load it as:

```
use t::Test::YourThing;
```

The upside is not having to write the `use lib` line in every test file, and clearly identifying it as a local test module.  The down side is cluttering up t/, it won't work if "." is not in `@INC` (for example, if you run your tests in taint mode, but it can be worked around with `use lib "."`) and if you decide to move the .pm file out of your project you have to rewrite all the uses.  Your choice.

Comment: Okay for the moment I'll go with this one even If I'll have a look at Test::Builder in a moment of time.

Answer (score 11):

The best approach is to put your test functions, like any other set of functions, into a module. You can then use [Test::Builder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::Builder) to have your test diagnostics/fail messages act as if the failure originated from the .t file, rather than your module.

Here is a simple example.

```
package Test::YourModule;

use Test::Builder;
use Sub::Exporter -setup => { exports => ['exitcode_ok'] };  # or 'use Exporter' etc.

my $Test = Test::Builder->new;

# Runs the command and makes sure its exit code is $expected_code. Contrived!
sub exitcode_ok {
    my ($command, $expected_code, $name) = @_;

    system($command);
    my $exit    = $? >> 8;
    my $message = $!;

    my $ok = $Test->is_num( $exit, $expected_code, $name );
    if ( !$ok ) {
        $Test->diag("$command exited incorrectly with the error '$message'");
    }

    return $ok;
}
```

In your script:

```
use Test::More plan => 1;
use Test::YourModule qw(exitcode_ok);
exitcode_ok('date', 0, 'date exits without errors');
```

Comment: I agree with all of this, but I would generally put test-specific functionality in a module in the t/ directory, so it cannot be confused with the actual application -- e.g. in MyApp/t/Common.pm, with the package name MyApp::t::Common.

Comment: I would recommend Test::Builder::Module as it will take care of writing a smart import() for you, one that can handle a test plan.  This allows your module to stand alone from Test::More.

Comment: This is a bit heavy handed when the common code you want to share isn't testing anything. Utility functions and various other things that aren't going to emit TAP won't benefit from a Test::Builder wrapper.